# Thread behaviour in Java

Tags: java

I am running the program below but for some reason, it dosen't look like I am getting to the run() method. Basically I am trying to spot the behaviour of threads.I am getting the result below :

pqni392fr8dchsdmajglvuqsof
pqni392fr8dchsdmajglvuqsof  has wake up 
l79uho1tjtot7pcmk4vhh5t8qc 
l79uho1tjtot7pcmk4vhh5t8qc  has wake up 
adfapus6g1fst56daimrudkgji
adfapus6g1fst56daimrudkgji  has wake up 
iqfo9knc99kcb622g36c77m62 
iqfo9knc99kcb622g36c77m62  has wake up 
67vdpghqit1a4iv3593451ps0a 
67vdpghqit1a4iv3593451ps0a  has wake up

As you see I am not getting to the run() method where a thread should sleep.what is the problem?
And another question, could a thread execute the run() from the first run of the program because I noticed that the first line of the output is always from the main().

Thank you.

---

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;



class myThread implements Runnable {

    @Override// method run is to be executed by a new thread
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("I am here");
        int timeRandom = new Random().nextInt(50);

        try {
            String ThrName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            Thread.sleep(timeRandom);
            System.out.println("Thread " + ThrName + " sleeping " + timeRandom);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(myThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");


    }
}

class myClass {

    static int nthread = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService myService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nthread);
        while (nthread != 0) {
            Thread.currentThread().setName(new BigInteger(130, new SecureRandom()).toString(32));
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            myService.submit(Thread.currentThread());

            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "  has wake up");
            //
            nthread -= 1;
        }
        myService.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: When I do that ,I am getting anonymous thread that runs, not the one that i already set a name for. And you get something like "Thread pool-1-thread-5 sleeping 8" ?

Comment: @user1207965 You're changing the name of the SAME thread, the one you are running in...

Answer (score 3):

You never pass an instance of `myThread` to your ExecutorService, and instead you are performing everything related onto the current thread.

Your code:

```
Thread.currentThread().setName(new BigInteger(130, new SecureRandom()).toString(32));
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
myService.submit(Thread.currentThread());
```

Code creating expected results:

```
Thread myThread = new Thread(new myThread());
myThread.setName(new BigInteger(130, new SecureRandom()).toString(32));
System.out.println(myThread.getName());
myService.submit(myThread);
```

Also, as a side note, Java conventions dictate that class names are declared with capital letters; myClass should be MyClass and myThread should be myThread.  That's irrelevant to the runtime issue though.

Comment: You could also use a `ThreadFactory`, but I guess there's enough confusion going around. Nice post though

Comment: Hi Vulcan,still I  am getting as output:Thread pool-1-thread-5 sleeping 4, etc,... <br> but not getting the already named thread to sleep !

Comment: That output comes from the line just before your call to make the thread sleep, correct? If so, your thread is either being interrupted, or it actually *is* sleeping but the 50 millisecond sleep time is unnoticeable.

Answer (score 2):

You are submitting the main thread for your application as a `Runnable` to the `ExecutorService` repeatedly. I'm not sure what the defined behavior (if any, could be undefined) of calling `run()` on the main thread is, but it is certainly not correct. You want to create new `myThread` objects and submit them to the `ExecutorService` instead.

Comment: Just in case anyone was curious, calling `run()` on the main thread in Oracle's JRE does nothing and returns.